# Mongoose allows non existed field for sorting. How can I restrict for existed fields only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below query returns data but **hgf** field does not exist in document(db). How can I restrict sorting only for existed fields?

```
files.find({ account_id: 1, deleted_at: { '$eq': null }, 
  status: { '$ne': 3 }}, { skip: 0, limit: 100, sort: { hgf: -1 }, projection: {} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
files.find({
  account_id: 1,
  deleted_at: { '$eq': null }, 
  status: { '$ne': 3 },
  hgf: { $exists: true, $ne: null } // Check it exists and not null
}, { skip: 0, limit: 100, sort: { hgf: -1 }, projection: {} });
```

Comment: Thanks @Dijkstra This works!! Returning empty array. But I am expecting error.